# Formatting a text area field in NetSuite to span over 3 columns

Tags: html, forms, netsuite

[image]

I was wondering if anyone knows how I could make text area fields in NetSuite span over the 3 columns.

These fields will have lots of text, so it would be nice to have the whole width of the page for each field.

Help would be much appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to replace the field group Notes with a tab called Notes and add the text area to the tab instead of to the field group (container property set to ID of tab). A test looks like this (I started with the sample Suitelet from Answer Id: 43586):
[image]

Here's the relevant snippet:

```
var subtab = form.addTab({
    id : 'custpage_subtab',
    label : 'Subtab'
});
var field = form.addField({
    id: 'textfield',
    type: serverWidget.FieldType.TEXTAREA,
    label: 'Text',
    container: 'custpage_subtab'
});
```

Field groups will always use a common layout, according to my tests. So, if there is one field group with 3 columns, then all field groups will have 3 columns and a field cannot span multiple columns, so the idea behind my solution is to use another element, in this case a tab element to display the field content. The tab label is not displayed because there is only one tab. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

```
  var fieldGroup = form.addFieldGroup({
    id: 'group_notes',
    label: 'Title'
  });

  var field = form.addField({
    id: 'textfield',
    type: ui.FieldType.TEXTAREA,
    label: 'Notes',
    container: 'group_notes'
  });

  field.updateLayoutType({
     layoutType: serverWidget.FieldLayoutType.OUTSIDEBELOW
  });
```

Relevant Netsuite documentation can be found [here](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/43603)